# Please explain form_for method in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, form-for

This isn't really a troubleshooting question but rather a request for an explanation. I'm having a hard time understanding the workings of the form_for method. Could someone explain to me what this method does in this situation. Here is my code for creating a form for the comments feature on a blog application. My code works, so i just want to understand WHY it works and How it works. Thanks!!

Here is my new comment form:

```
<%= form_for([@post, @post.comments.build]) do |c| %> 
<p>
    <%= c.label :content, class: "col-md control-label" %><br> 
    <%= c.text_area :content, rows: "10", class: "form-control"  %>
</p> 

<p> 
    <%= c.submit %> 
</p> 

<% end %>
```

And here is my code for the comments Controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController 
    def new 
        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    end 

    def create 
        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id]) 
        @comment = @post.comments.create(comment_params) 
        @comment.user_id = current_user.id 
        @comment.save 
        #redirect_to post_path(@post) 
        redirect_to posts_path 

    end 

    private 

    def comment_params 
        params.require(:comment).permit(:content)
    end
 end
```

In particular, what does the "[@post, @post.comments.build]" parameter of form_for do?

Comment: It will generate `url` like `post_comment_url`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First off, there's nothing you can do with `form_for` that you couldn't do with `form_tag` (and some extra typing).

What `form_for` allows you to do is easily create forms that fit with the rails conventions in terms of urls & parameter naming.

The first argument to `form_for` is the resource that is being edited or created. At it's simplest this might be just `@post`. The array form is for namespaces or nested resources.

Your example of `[@post, @post.comments.build]` means that this is a form for a new comment (the last element of the array is an unsaved instance of Comment) that is nested under that specific post. This will result in the form doing a POST request to `/posts/1234/comments` (assuming the post has an id of 1234). The corresponding nested route needs to exist for this to work.

The second thing `form_for` does for you is allow you to write `c.text_area :content` and have that automatically use the correct parameter name (comment[content]) and have the value prefilled with the current value of the comment's `content` attribute.

Comment: Thanks so much bro! Your explanation really helped!! I've been struggling to wrap my head around the workings of form_for!

Answer (score 2):

The form_for will do a *post* to a specific resource and help to draw the inputs.

**Example 1**

`form_for(@post)` will do a *post* to `myapp/posts/create` and draw the posts fields

**Example 2**

`form_for([@post, @post.comments.build])` will do a *post* to `myapp/posts/:post_id/comments/create` and draw the comments fields

Comment: Can you explain this part of code: `@comment = @post.comments.create(comment_params)`

Comment: For example: `@post.comments.create(comment_params)` will create a comment related with the `@post`

Answer (score 0):

here [@post, @post.comments.build] means this form is for a new comment, and form will do a POST request to /posts/post_id/comments (post_id is a @post.id)